# Why my localhost/wp-admin/install.php shows me a blank page?

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, mariadb, opensuse

Hi I'm beginner for developing the website. I currently using the OpenSuse Linux platform. I have installed the wordpress based on the http://www.itzgeek.com/web/wordpress/install-wordpress-on-opensuse-13-2-with-lamp.html
URL. However, when I access this URL (localhost/wp-admin/install.php) , it shows nothing. It just gives me a blank page.

Comment: First thing _always_ to do if you have an issue with php in a web environment: take a look into your http servers error log file. That is where you can read what the issue is instead of having to guess or ask.

Answer (score 0):

Login with root user in a terminal and run below command to check existing error if exists.

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log
```

After executed the command, refresh install page and watch terminal. If new line added, There is an error. Then write it here until we solve your problem.

Good luck.

Comment: [Thu Mar 09 09:42:19.791559 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 1453] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]

Comment: [Thu Mar 09 09:42:19.905721 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1453] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Linux/SUSE) OpenSSL/1.0.1i-fips PHP/5.6.30 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Mar 09 09:42:19.905770 2017] [core:notice] [pid 1453] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd2-prefork -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -D SYSTEMD -D FOREGROUND'

Comment: [Thu Mar 09 19:52:23.863004 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 1318] AH01882: Init: this version of mod_ssl was compiled against a newer library (OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015, version currently loaded is OpenSSL 1.0.1i-fips 6 Aug 2014) - may result in undefined or erroneous behavior
AH00557: httpd2-prefork: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for linux-kny7
AH00558: httpd2-prefork: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

Comment: [Thu Mar 09 19:52:33.915213 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 1318] AH01882: Init: this version of mod_ssl was compiled against a newer library (OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015, version currently loaded is OpenSSL 1.0.1i-fips 6 Aug 2014) - may result in undefined or erroneous behavior
[Thu Mar 09 19:52:33.915299 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 1318] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]

Comment: [Thu Mar 09 19:52:35.175637 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1318] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Linux/SUSE) OpenSSL/1.0.1i-fips PHP/5.6.30 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Mar 09 19:52:35.175813 2017] [core:notice] [pid 1318] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd2-prefork -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -D